# In PHP, can I differentiate the result of intval(null) from intval("0")?

Tags: php

I get input values via POST, some of them might be ID's referring to other things, and some start at 0. When choosing something with ID 0, or something without a value, is there a method like `intval()` that returns something more helpful than `0` on failure to parse? Or can I somehow differentiate the result of `intval()` from the failure to parse?

Example:

```
echo intval(null); // 0
echo intval("0");  // 0
```

Comment: How about testing them *before* you cast them to a value that can't be null or string?  :P  The expressions `null !== 0`, `"0" !== 0`, and `"0" !== null` are all true.

Comment: A simple `if ($val === null)` is what you need here.

Comment: You can use PHP gettype function. And compare if its NULL or INTEGER. Will be string if quoted. http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php

Comment: If the values come from a post, it's not likely that the value you wish to compare is actually `null`.

Comment: @Jack - it might be undefined (ie if it wasn't included in the POST at all), in which case `null` would be the default, once you ignore the PHP undefined warnings.

Comment: @cHao I know several ways of doing it that would give the correct result, but my main problem is that I don't find it should be necessary. Rather it's more likely that I'm using the wrong method for this purpose, in which case Jack's answer is spot on. Though I guess type conversion would still ruin my ideas of clean code, even with `filter_var`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`filter_var()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function to determine the difference:

```
filter_var(null, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
// false

filter_var('0', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
// int(0)
```

You can also add flags to specifically accept hexadecimal and octal values, but I wouldn't recommend that for your case.

Btw, in the more likely case that the variable comes from `$_POST`, you can also use `filter_input()`:

```
if (is_int($nr = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nr', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))) {
    // $nr contains an integer
}
```

The reason I'm using `is_int()` on the result of `filter_input` is because when nothing is posted, `null` is returned; using `is_int()` guards against this issue.

**Edit**

If the question is really just about `null` vs `'0'` you can just compare `$var !== null`:

```
if (!is_null($var)) {
    // $var is definitely not null
    // but it might also be an object, string, integer, float even, etc.
}
```

Comment: Beware it uses filter extension (included in php base extensions since PHP 5.2)

Comment: Of course this doesn't really solve anything because you now have to distinguish between `0` and `false`... :)

Comment: @ДамянСтанчев You're right, I tested it wrongly on the command line :)

Comment: @Jack: So why not use `null !==` to begin with? :)

Comment: @Jon hehe, perhaps he also wanted to test empty strings?

Comment: @Jack Well I guess it's not really vs null, I just found it to be something that type converted to 0. You understood what I meant and not what I wrote :)

Comment: @VIPINJAIN: Beware to not use outdated PHP versions in publicly accessible environments like a website.

Answer (score 0):

You could first check if its a number:

```
is_numeric($val);
```

Comment: but not int, all numbers (float too)

Comment: but if it's a number and intval returns 0, you'll know the value is 0. If it's not a number and intval returns 0, you'll know it's something other than 0 (like null)

Answer (score -2):

Ok, now go for the solution.

```
preg_match('/^\d+$/','0') //is true

preg_match('/^\d+$/',NULL) //is false
```

Comment: This is entirely equivalent to `is_numeric($value)`.  `is_int(intval(anything))` is useless, as it will always be true; when do you expect something converted to int not to be an int?

Comment: @cHao : Please test the code first :) and one more thing if the first condition is false then the next expression is not evaluated. PHP Docs says that

Comment: I don't care whether it works.  My point is, you're doing useless tests.  You test it first, with and without everything including and following the `&&`, and see if you don't get the exact same results in both cases.

Comment: @cHao : Please check the question first.

Comment: It *doesn't matter* whether the second half of the `&&` is evaluated, because *that side will always be true*.  There is no case whatsoever where `intval($whatever)` is not an int.

Comment: @cHao : Please check the question and please evaluate the script according to the same. Nothing is useless here!! The OP wants to check for int value and also he wants to exclude NULL form the integers

Comment: I beg to differ.  This is.  You're doing stuff that's not just useless, it adds noise to the code that shouldn't be there.

Comment: You're really not getting it.  `intval($x)` *always, always* returns an integer.  Testing to *see* whether it's an integer is useless, as you already know the answer if you have any clue how `intval` works.

Comment: @cHao : ok i got it. so i m changing it